Faces are aprear differently
Faces on the object appear to be different after modeling. I think it is because of the star that was formed while modelling 

hello, not sure to understand, maybe recalculate the normals (Shift N)? If it doesn't work please share your file

I just find out. Those faces were flipt for some reason. I flipped them back and everything's ok now.  I did recalculate the normals before,  but it helped only where it could help.

I think you also have overlapping faces, even if you don't notice it right now.

Yes, that was true. I deleted all overlapping faces.
